# To run commands on different linux nide by jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I want to jenkins to execute a list of commands on different linux node in a network.
What steps should I take to run a command on another linux node by adrressing its ip address

Answer (score 1):

if I understood you correctly you should add this node as a slave machine to the Jenkins.
go to Manage Jenkins section and then to Manage Nodes and just add a new Node

Answer (score 1):

once you added the nodes.
in pilpeline groovy script
use :

```
node('node1'){
//command execution
}
node('node2'){
//command execution
}
```